# Запятые в выражении "Ну ты(,) Вася(,) и чудак!"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять имя запятыми в предложении: *"Ну ты(,) Вася(,) и чудак!"?*

Мне кажется, что нужно, но почему? Это вроде не обращение в данном случае, тогда уточнение или что?

Answer (score 6):

А почему не обращение-то?

*Ну ты, Вася, и чудак!*

А если перестроить:

*Ну, ты и чудак, Вася!*

*Вася, ну ты и чудак!*

Он же обращается к собеседнику, а не говорит о ком-то третьем, значит, обращение.

Comment: _Людмила: А почему не обращение - то?_ === Гм... Похоже, Вы правы!

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно! Потом подумал, что это может всё-таки и быть обращением. А вот в Вашем примере "Ну, ты и чудак, Вася!" разве нужна запятая после "ну"?

Comment: "Ну" может быть частицей, а может - междометием, тогда запятая ставится.Здесь явно междометие, пауза напрашивается, а "ну" вносит удивление.

Comment: А мне казалось частицей казалось, и без паузы я говорил.